# Is there any reason to namespace structure members in C?

Tags: c, data-structures

In C, such as in many POSIX structures, the structure members are prefixed with an abbreviated version of the structure such as:

```
struct passwd {
    char *pw_name;
    char *pw_passwd;
    uid_t pw_uid;
    gid_t pw_gid;
    time_t pw_change;
    char *pw_class;
    char *pw_gecos;
    char *pw_dir;
    char *pw_shell;
    time_t pw_expire;
};
```

All the members are prefixed with `pw_` which is presumably short for the structure name `passwd`. I do not believe that structure members can name clash with existing variables in the scope, they seem to have their own namespace. I.e., the following [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/1WErqTEjT):

```
struct { int x; } x;
x.x;
```

As such, is there any reason to *'namespace'* structure members manually by prefixing them? Why is this a common practice?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35874187/prefixes-in-member-names-of-a-struct